# Is it possible to use a PHP variable from the main php page in an php included file?

Tags: php, variables

I have a "main" php webpage called "main.php" and I have an included file called "comments.php".

In main.php I'm using the following to get the url of the page, but I'm trying to use the $shareURL variable in the included file (comments.php) and it isn't working.

**Code In Main.php**

```
<?php $shareURL = "http://".$_SERVER[\'SERVER_NAME\'] . $_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\']; ?>
```

Above is the variable.
Below is the include.

```
<?php include "$domainName/assets/includes/fbCommentBox.php"; ?>
```

**Code in the Include File (comment.php)**

```
<?php echo "<div class='fb-comments' data-href='$shareURL' data-num-posts='5' data-width='100%'></div>"; ?>
```

If I use the above in my included file, I get the pages URL for the include file, not the main.php page.

Is there a method to use a php variable within the main.php page that will pass its value into the included (comments.php) file?

**SCOPE OF THE PROJECT**

The main.php code is being placed 'inside' of another php variable that is being used to create a webpage. I need the `\` in `<?php $shareURL = "http://".$_SERVER[\'SERVER_NAME\'] . $_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\']; ?>`.

**Example**

```
<?php
$content = ' 
<?php $shareURL = "http://".$_SERVER[\'SERVER_NAME\'] . $_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\']; ?>
';
?>
```

Comment: please show _how_ you try to use the variable. It should be no problem actually. Included files are treated as if it was one file.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the code i'm using

Comment: Mr.B, I reproduced your code (with some modifications) here and it should work. try to use ['SERVER_NAME'] instead of [\'SERVER_NAME\'] (do the same for REQUEST_URI)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem either. No matter if I declare the `$shareURL` in the main.php file or in some include.php file within a couple of other dirs, the result remains the same.

Comment: @MarcelKohls, thank you for your help, but I'm using the `\` because that line of code is inside of another variable being used to write that code to a file the writes a final webpage.

Comment: @Mr.B, try to show more about your code. Maybe your problem is not clearly explained.

Comment: If your question is about the variable, see what PHP manual says:
When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` returns the domain. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns the path where the script was called by the user. So if the user visits _https://example.com/test/_, the result will be _https://example.com/test/_ no matter if those variables are declared in some index.php file inside _/test/_ or some include.php file inside _/test/some/other/folder/_

Comment: ok, I think I understand what are you trying to do. You are trying to declare the $shareURL into another PHP file by passing it as a string. And you are expecting that this $shareURL should be automatic declarated after inserted. right?

Comment: @MarcelKohls yes, I'm trying to pass the url as a string and use that string in the included file.

Comment: @Mr.B and why don't you directly declare the $shareURL ?

Comment: @MarcelKohls I need it to be a variable because it will change for each different webpage the comment include is on. 

The comment code will be on every page and I need the comment code to be tied the to URL of the page. There will be thousands of pages.

Comment: ok, I think I understand. Try to use anonymous functions on that variable, it should return what you expect: $shareURL = function(){ return "http:...".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."...."; }

Comment: @Mr.B instead of anonymous function, try to use the anonymous class and the magic method __toSring: $shareURL = new class{
        public function __toString() {
            return "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
    }

Comment: @MarcelKohls1st, thanks for working on this with me. I greatly appreciate it. 2nd, I've decided to simplify the question and post it here with full code and output. It might be clearer. Can you please take a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858279/how-use-a-php-variable-declared-in-the-parent-file-into-the-included-file

Answer (score 0):

A better [than globals], though possibly more involved, approach would be to have all the code in the included file wrapped in functions or in a class, and then passing the variable into those functions when you call them from the main file.

EDIT: Removed my suggestion of using `global`, per the comment below. `global` only applies if you are sharing a variable between scopes, i.e. between one function and another or between a function body and the global space.

Comment: You don't need `global` to use variables from an included file. `global` is tangential to the asked question (at least if it's read exactly).