# How use a php variable declared in the parent file in an included file

Tags: php, variables, scope, include

I'm trying to pass the php variable `$shareURL = "someURL";` from the parent page of test.php into the included file of commentTest.php. Is this possible? If yes, please help.

**Parent File = Test.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    $shareURL = "someURL";
    echo "$shareURL";
    include "http://domainName.net/assets/includes/commentTest.php"; 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Included File = commentTest.php**

```
<?PHP 
echo "<div class='fb-comments' data-href='$shareURL' data-num-posts='5' data-width='100%'></div>";
?>
```

**HTML Output Source**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    someURL<div class='fb-comments' data-href='' data-num-posts='5' data-width='100%'></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php show you? Including an external url may not be letting you. At best, you can try to get to use `file_get_contents()` instead. See the manual on include https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: You should befine but be carefull not to turn it into 'spagetti' code. I stopped using this method because of it. Also, i would suggest to rempve the 'optional' closing tag `?>`as it can add unwanted whitespace at the end of the include.

Comment: @Mr.B  I still suggest you to use the anonymous class, did you tried it? $shareURL = new class{
        public function __toString() {
            return "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
    };

Comment: Can't this be applied using session?

Comment: You need to include the file by path for this to work, e.g.: `include 'assets/includes/commentTest.php';`

Comment: so `include 'assets/includes/commentTest.php';` works, but it won't work in my case because I need the path to be root relative. I tried `include '/assets/includes/commentTest.php';` and that didn't work because it wasn't the actual root (don't totally understand why). I found this `dirname(__FILE__)` and it works when used like this - `include "$root/assets/includes/commentTest.php";` Apparently my root is this `/var/www/html`. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

Your comments and answers helped me find the solution I needed.

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
include "$root/assets/includes/commentTest.php";
```

Apparently my root is here `/var/www/html` instead of right after the TLD in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Test.php to this:

`include "/assets/includes/commentTest.php";`

Comment: this is actually a correct answer, i'd give this a plus one if you gave the reason why the OP needs to make this change

Comment: I had to use this `$root = dirname(__FILE__);
 include "$root/assets/includes/commentTest.php";`